# Filming Locations of The Space Between Us

Tags: film-location, the-space-between-us

I was looking at the movie [The Space Between Us](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3922818/), and on some of the aerial shots, there is a beautiful scenery of dark green and yellow trees.
I've looked at the Filming Locations in [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3922818/locations?ref_=tt_dt_dt) and other sources I could find and they are most likely in Albuquerque, New Mexico, USA.

But I would like a more exact location to google so I can see more pictures of this place:

[image: film screenshot]

Comment: Maybe someone can shed some light on why this question has been down-voted?

Comment: yes, I too would like to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scene was filmed in Colorado.
On CO-145 near Ophir between Ophir Rd & Old Butterfly Rd. - heading north.
(Note: a stunt woman rode the bike - not Britt, there are some tweets about it out there)

BTW: Just about half a mile south is where they filmed the scene where they're driving into the valley (in the BMW) - this time heading south.

Comment: thank you! I found some wonderful photos of the filming locations!